# In PowerShell how to get a Get-WBVolume without a volume path?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove a dead volume from the backup policy, but to remove it you must specify it in the remove command. But I can not figure out how to specify a volume to remove if it doesn't have a volume path...

How would I go about getting a WBVolume for a volume without a volume path?
Here's the volume info I have:

```
VolumeLabel :
MountPath   :
MountPoint  : \\?\Volume{b193b193-0000-0000-0000-406b3b000000}
FileSystem  : NTFS
Property    : Critical, ValidSource
FreeSpace   : 367382528
TotalSpace  : 854589440
```

I am trying to remove it from a WBPolicy but to remove it, it must be specified some thing like this:
`$Volume = Get-WBVolume -VolumePath "?"`

so a cmdlet like this will work `Remove-WBVolume -Policy $Policy -Volume $Volume`

Comment: Can you select the volume and pipe it to `Remove-WBVolume`?

Comment: Yea, that's the issue I have no way to select it, as best as I can tell to use the Get-WBVolume to select the volume you need to specify the VolumePath. the only way I can get it to list is with the Get-WBVolume -AllVolumes, Which show me all of the volumes known to WB. But I can't seem to figure out how to list it individually

Comment: Maybe you can exclude all volumes that have a path, excuse my guesses I'm unable to test at the moment. `Get-WBVolume -AllVolumes | Where-Object { $_.MountPath -eq $null }`

Comment: Good try, Thanks. But no dice. After I the ran your command (no errors reported) I dumped the variable $Volume. The variable $Volume was empty...Rats

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a WBVolume with no value in mountpath and volumelabel you could use the below:

```
Get-WBVolume -AllVolumes | where {$_.mountpath -lt 0 -and $_.volumelabel -lt 0}
```

You should then be able to pipe this into Remove-WBVolume